# Argument Forwarding in PHP

Tags: php, arguments, forwarding

Consider the following functions:

```
function debug() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  // process $args
}

function debug_die() {
  // call debug() with the passed arguments
  die;
}
```

The method `debug_die` exits after calling `debug` that takes a variable number of arguments.

So the arguments passed to `debug_die` as such are meant for `debug` only and just have to be forwarded. How can this be done in the `debug_die` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function debug_die() {
    call_user_func_array("debug", func_get_args());
    die;
}
```